# Oracle 11.2.0.3 to 11.2.0.4

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, upgrade

I'm planning to upgrade 3 instances of Oracle (all same Oracle Home) from 11.2.0.3 to 11.2.0.4. I'm going through the installer and I get to the question about Upgrade or install just the database software. I only want to upgrade one instance initially and leave the others running on 11.2.0.3 in parallel. My question is, what's the difference between:

`Install database software only
Upgrade an existing database`

I really don't want to touch the other SIDs on there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choose `Install database software only`, then later you can upgrade your databases one by one with DBUA (Database Upgrade Assistant) from the new Oracle Home, or by performing a manual upgrade.

Comment: Thank you, I did a bit more research and I agree this is the safest approach.